# Golang go1.14.7.linux-amd64.tar.gz checksum not matching

Tags: linux, go, checksum, sha256

https://golang.org/dl/ shows a different SHA256 checksum versus what I downloaded into my VPS:

> go1.14.7.linux-amd64.tar.gz   Archive     Linux   x86-64  118MB   4a7fa60f323ee1416a4b1425aefc37ea359e9d64df19c326a58953a97ad41ea5

I'm getting different values:

> sha256sum go1.14.7.linux-amd64.tar.gz
> 353f6c251ab323f7435d107577f1504d3c4f74af4ebb06fa2d3c71fc7560f4f3  go1.14.7.linux-amd64.tar.gz

I downloaded it using

> curl -O https://golang.org/dl/go1.14.7.linux-amd64.tar.gz

What's going on here? Is it possible the golang.org values are not updated? Man-in-the-middle attack or similar?

Comment: Check the downloaded file, it's just a placeholder. you need to tell `curl` to follow redirects with `-L`

Comment: Thanks! Just submitted the option missing to the Digitalocean HOWTO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you're seeing is due to not using the `-L` option, which performs automatic redirects.  The link you use redirects to the real location and provides a stub HTML page to perform the redirection should you be using a browser that doesn't properly support the `Location` header.  As a result, the hash you're getting is of a small, incomplete HTML file, not the real Go archive.

If I don't use the `-L` option, I get the result you reported; if I do, then I get the expected result as listed on the download page.  Note that if you have a trusted, strong checksum or signature for an archive that you verify, it's always safe to use the `-L` option, since you're going to verify the archive manually and an attacker won't be able to tamper with it.

Comment: Thanks! Just submitted the option missing to the Digitalocean HOWTO